# Ruby Mongodb driver $gt acts as $gte in date conditions, why?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a weird situation with `$gt` and `$gte` conditions in ruby mongodb driver.

So here is code:

```
timeline = timeline_db.find({date: {"$gt" => s_time}, username: { "$in" => followers_array } }, sort:["date", Mongo::DESCENDING], limit: 10)
```

Problem is that this query return item with *exactly* that time I'm requesting, which would be valid if I wrote `$gte` instead.

`$gte` does return exactly same result as `$gt`. Why does it happen?

Comment: Are you sure even the fractional part of the time is the same?

Comment: It seems there is a bug, because if I subtract or add 1 seconds to conditional time it starts works as it supposed to.

Comment: same problem here with php and also on mongo console. Did you find any solution?