# Querying dates in mongodb problems with $gt operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple query

```
db.myobject.find({"dateTimeSent" : {"$gt" : ISODate("2013-12-05T18:05:25Z")}})
```

I am expecting the query to return all documents that have the date in dateTimeSent to be greater then 2013-12-05T18:05:25Z.  For some reason it also returns documents with that exact date.  It is acting as $gte.  Is this a bug in mongodb?

Comment: which version of mongo are you using? I am using 2.4.8 and it is working as expected.

Comment: we are running version 2.2.3

Comment: Most probably it is a bug. There is a similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300336/ruby-mongodb-driver-gt-acts-as-gte-in-date-conditions-why. Upgrade to new version and try it there.

Comment: Yes it does look like a bug.  Version 2.4.8 works fine.